# dll built with 3rd party dll stops working when 3rd party software changes version

Tags: .net, dll, versioning

If I am provided with a 3rd party dll, say version 1.1

then I build a dll of my own referencing this 3rd party dll (version 1.1)

now I supply my dll back to this 3rd party.  my dll has been built using they 1.1 "api" dll.

Now the 3rd party changes the version of their dll, which is also used within their software to version 1.2

After this, their software can no longer use my dll compiled with version 1.1 until I recompile my plugin dll with their version 1.2 dll.

How can this problem be resolved?

Comment: Did you set "Specific Version" to "True" for the reference you added to that DLL? If answer is yes simply set it to "False" (I suppose, of course, you don't need to change your code too to upgrade from 1.1 to 1.2...)

Comment: Thanks, I have set Specific Version to false, and there are no changes to any interfaces or functionality.  The error from the 3rd party is like a dll loader exception.  Could this be a problem on their end?

Comment: It could be an error on their side but to diagnose you need a more detailed report...

Comment: Here is the error from their side:Could not load file or assembly 'company.class.Client, Version=1.1.8.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b0d2f667011a393b' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Is it company.class.Client your assembly or their assembly?

Comment: that is their assembly, we could call that the API dll

Comment: Hmmmmm you should check the log, somewhere there should be a "hard" reference to version (or another issue, it's not sure it's beacause of assembly version). I have no other ideas without more data, sorry

Comment: Yeah we are puzzled too.  We thought that was it, but in the debugging it is asking for the old version 1.1.8.2 instead of current 1.1.9.1.  Thanks.

Comment: SpecificVersion only works to get your program compiled.  It won't work at runtime, the CLR insists to get an exact match with the reference assembly.  A strong DLL Hell counter measure.  Other than a bindingRedirect, the best thing to do is to just update the reference assembly.  You'll never have an Oops that way.

Comment: It really sounds like this company providing the API needs to review their plugin conventions. Having said that, you only need to worry about when that vendor *changes* their product - kind of like, should you expect that a plugin written for Word 2010 will continue to work in Word 2012. 
I would reasonably expect that breakages are only occurring when your vendor releases a significant upgrade - if not, revisit my first remark! (not much help to you I know, but could be worth discussing with the vendor)

Answer (score 0):

Consumers of your assembly that reference a newer version of an assembly you depend upon should use the [`<bindingRedirect>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) in their application configuration file, like so:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="myDependency"
                              publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0"
                             newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Note that `myDepdendency` is the name of the assembly that you are dependent on that's been upgraded.

This is used commonly in Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC; adding them through NuGet usually results in the above sections being added to your application configuration file.

Comment: thanks you casper, I will do some research and if this works I will accept your answer.  Thanks.